# Bind Locks Offline scope

Tags: tapkey

Im currently integrating the TapKey side of a DOM lock integration and I'm having trouble with a specific scope required by DOM.

https://developers.tapkey.io/openapi/tapkey_access_management_web_api_v1/#/Bound%20Locks/PhysicalLocks_StartOfflineBinding

When adding the bind:locks:offline scope to my list, i get an 'invalid_scope' error returned, the rest of the scopes work without a problem.

Am i doing something wrong regarding the scope? Or does this one need to be activated somewhere else by yourselves?

invalid_scope returned, then 401 unauthorized when trying the API with my current scope list.

Answer (score 0):

Every scope to be used must be enabled for the OAuth Client upfront in the in the integrator portal of Tapkey (portal.tapkey.io) otherwise the authentication request will fail with invalid_scope.

The scope `bind:locks:offline` is a special scope, which is not available by default. Please get in touch with Tapkey support to explain the case and ask for enabling that feature for your integrator account.